# Change css class attributes of style sheet on button click in asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

On page I want user can change background of page, apply background image to page. On save click this changed background should be saved in css class.

Suppose my css class is

```
#content 
{
    background:green;
}
```

As shown if I select blue color then blue color should be applied to that page background.

And on save button click css should change to

```
#content 
{
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to store the background in user's profile? And provide him the same background when he logs back in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$('#saveButtonId').click(function() {
    $('#content').css('background','blue');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use css() in jquery

```
   $('#saveButton').click(function() {

        $("#content").css('background','blue');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's not dynamically loaded then you can use:

```
 $("#id").click(function ()
 {
    $('#content').css('background','blue');
 });
```

If it's dynamically loaded:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#id", function() {
  $('#content').css('background','blue');
});
```